# How to make R binary *.zip windows 10 file from *.tar.gz file?

Tags: r, package, rdcomclient

I want to make  (if possible) zip file from tar.gz file that is for RDCOMClient R package.

I installed that package using this code:

```
devtools::install_github("omegahat/RDCOMClient")
```

So I have got it installed but for the future use I want to save it as binary zip file in order not to compile it each and every time when I have to. Installation from zip file is faster and easier.

I tried to use this: https://builder.r-hub.io/ but it did not work at all.

How do I do  it ?  Is it doable ?

I am expecting to obtain zip file binary for windows 10 x64 R 4.2.1 version.